# Securing database connexion and mysql requests

Tags: php, mysql, database, connexion

Here is my db.php file which contains the php connexion script

```
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=;host=;charset=utf8', 'login', 'pwd');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

and here is my way of doing a php request to mysql

```
    // select
    $req = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM customer WHERE phone = ?");
    $req->execute([$_POST['phone']]);
    $user = $req->fetch();

    // insert
    $req = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET phone = ?, password = ?, email = ");
    $req->execute([$_POST['phone'], $password, $_POST['email']);
```

I would like to make sure that my approach is safe and secure? What do you think ? can I do better? How ?

Comment: Secure against what exactly? It should be ok against SQL injection, but what other threats are you intending to mitigate against?

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes sql injection particularly and other risks and vulnerabilities eventually when we deal with php and mysql (for example should I use other functions like htmlentities,addcslashes, etc)

Comment: The only answer to that is "it depends what you're going to do with the piece of data you're running those functions on". You need to be more specific about the threats and the usage of the data. Then again you can also read general advice about this sort of thing in a good number of places already online. It's hard for us to judge your existing level of knowledge about this topic.